# reactjs need data from MySQL add before code can resume - can I use a 'then' somewhere

Tags: mysql, reactjs, promise, foreign-keys, primary-key

The following code adds a record and then rereads table to get the added records Id (variable 'rid') so it can be used to add child detail records. rid never gets a value.
It seems I need some type of 'then' logic or '}' adjustment so the master record gets added before I try to go back and reread it.

Any ideas?

...

```
copyReportCard = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var X = parseInt(this.state.selectedreportcardmasterid, 10)
    ReportCardMasterService.getReportCardMasterById(X).then((res) =>{
        let reportcardmaster = res.data;
        let sitereportcardmaster = {
            sitereportcardmasterCode: this.state.rCode,
            sitereportcardmasterName: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterName,
            sitereportcardmastergradeLimit: reportcardmaster.reportcardmastergradeLimit,
            sitereportcardmasterColora: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterColora,
            sitereportcardmasterColorb: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterColorb,
            sitereportcardmasterColorc: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterColorc,
            sitereportcardmasterColord: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterColord,
            sitereportcardmasterColore: reportcardmaster.reportcardmasterColore,
            sitereportcardmastercpymasterId: reportcardmaster.reportcardmastercpymasterId,
            sitereportcardmasterComments: '',
            sitereportcardmasterCategorytotal: '',
            sitemaster_sitemasterId:this.props.match.params.sitemaster_sitemasterid
        };
        SiteReportCardMasterService.createSiteReportCardMaster(sitereportcardmaster);
    });
    SiteReportCardMasterService.getSiteReportCardMaster().then((res) => {
        this.setState({ sitereportcardmaster: res.data});
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.sitereportcardmaster.length; i++) 
        {
            if (this.state.sitereportcardmaster[i].sitereportcardmasterCode === this.state.rCode){
               this.setState({rid: this.state.sitereportcardmaster[i].sitereportcardmasterid})};
            }
    ReportCardDetailsService.getReportCardDetails().then((res) => {
        this.setState({reportcarddetails: res.data});
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.reportcarddetails.length; i++) 
        {
            var X = parseInt(this.state.selectedreportcardmasterid,10);
            if (this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcardmaster_reportcardmasterId === X)
                {
                let sitereportcarddetails = 
                    {
                        sitereportcarddetailsSequence: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsSequence,
                        sitereportcarddetailsDescription: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsDescription,
                        sitereportcarddetailsCriteria: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsCriteria,
                        sitereportcarddetailsWeight: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsWeight,
                        sitereportcarddetailsScore: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsScore,
                        sitereportcarddetailsWeightedscore: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsWeightedscore,
                        sitereportcarddetailsColor: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsColor,
                        sitereportcarddetailsComment: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailsComment,
                        reportcarddetailcategory_reportcarddetailcategoryId: this.state.reportcarddetails[i].reportcarddetailcategory_reportcarddetailcategoryId,
                        sitereportcardmaster_sitereportcardmasterId: this.state.rid
                    }
                    SiteReportCardDetailsService.createSiteReportCardDetails(sitereportcarddetails);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for certain but you probably just want an extra `.then()` to chain the second phase to the first phase.

As a bonus, the nested `.then()` in the second phase can be unnested.

You might end up with something like this ...

```
copyReportCard = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var X = parseInt(this.state.selectedreportcardmasterid, 10);
    return ReportCardMasterService.getReportCardMasterById(X)
    .then((res) => {
        ...
        return SiteReportCardMasterService.createSiteReportCardMaster(...);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return SiteReportCardMasterService.getSiteReportCardMaster();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ 'sitereportcardmaster': res.data });
        ...
        return ReportCardDetailsService.getReportCardDetails();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ 'reportcarddetails': res.data });
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.reportcarddetails.length; i++) {
            ...
        }
    });
};
```

Note that successful sequencing relies on returning promises from the first three `.then()` clauses.

Also, `copyReportCard()` now returns Promise to its caller (though it appears to be top level code).

Comment: Wow....your solution works!  What is even better is that I learned a little more about proper formatting\syntax with IF statements in Reactjs and managing results when dealing with Promises.
I thank you for time and interest!

Comment: @HighwayRob, you can count yourself as noob++ now :-)